# Survival Distribution

Tags: distribution

I need to do a survival distribution on eight plant species over a 13 month period. I'm using:

survreg(Surv(Time, Site) ~ Red Mulberry + Persimmon + Soapberry + Beautyberry + Mustang Grape + Elderberry + Heartleaf Peppervine + Coralberry, dist='weibull', data=fs)

I keep getting an error saying

Error: unexpected symbol in "survreg(Surv(time, Site) ~ Red Mulberry"

Answer (score 0):

How about rename your variables?, for example: omit space in variable's name, so "Red_Mulberry" instead of "Red Mulberry"